# JS load problem after shifting mongodb from Heroku to localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku

After shifting from a mongodb hosted on Heroku to one hosted locally, suddenly the javascript in our nodejs project doesn't load properly. What is causing this?

When you run the site, the html is calling js entities that are 'not found', even then in the load waterfall it's clear that the declaration file is loaded.

Any idea why this would happen? Can't work out why shifting the mongodb location would cause this, otherwise nothing else has changed.

Comment: do you have any stacktrace? Are you connected? Did you migrate all the collections?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon Thanks. `Uncaught ReferenceError: loadPortfolioPanel is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1)
onclick @ (index):1
` is the stacktrace. The collections are loaded, and db is connected. It's somehow a javascript error, because it is trying to call a variable references in controllers.js which has loaded and is otherwise called on the same page.

Comment: Any thoughts @ManuelSpigolon? Thanks.